# Prove or disprove: If $A$, $B$ are similar matrices then $A$ and $B$ are row-equivalent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove or disprove: If $A$, $B$ are similar matrices then $A$ and $B$ are row-equivalent. Can anyone help me solve this ?

Comment: Given a counter example to prove the statement is false

Answer (score 0):

Similar matrix have same rank can you proceed further?